# Disabling automount in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, automount

I have installed dconf-editor and checked the top two boxes to disable automount and automount-run, but it does not do the trick. All partitions are still mounted on plug in.

This is annoying. Is the only solution to disable the gnome-desktop and move to i3?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was doing the dconf-editor on the root account.

I did it on the user account and automount was disabled.

But that broke gnome-terminal, which now hangs.

Console tty3 repeats the message "usb_set_interface failed (-110)"

The whole system freaked out. Had to power down and remove .config/dconf to return to operation.